# Speed up this (basic) node.js server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a (stupid) node.js server that is here for the sole purpose of calling a function on the data it's passed with each request and answer the result of that function. Here is the code I use:

```
var pageDown = require('./PageDown/Markdown.Sanitizer').getSanitizingConverter(),
 http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var data = "";
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    res.end(pageDown.makeHtml(data));
  });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('HServer running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I use this server from python with the following code (atm I'm just benchmarking so it's just a stress test):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

for i in range(1, 100000):
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:1337/', data="lol")
    print i
print "I'm done :')"
```

My problem is that this way of getting things done is slow. I have a large database that needs to be processed with this javascript function and I'm looking for ways to make the above process quicker. So suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your are doing is calling the node process to cleanup your HTML, why not just do that in python?  I assume the markdown converter you are pointing to is this one: http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js.  If that is the case, why not convert it to python (or find similar python code), and work with it in process.  It seems nuts to make a network call to simply run this process since it will be much much slower than just doing it all in python.  Here are some python markdown tools I was able to find: http://packages.python.org/Markdown/, https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2.

Comment: yeah well I kinda know that I could rewrite the whole library, but my intend is not to do that, precisely. And sadly it's not the classic markdown, there are additions to it, and those additions are available in C# and js only (and I won't touch C#).

Comment: That sucks.  Not sure what you can do then because its going to be that network call that is going to cause you a lot of overhead.  If its not fast enough, maybe there are other node markdown libraries that can replace it that might be faster - https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-markdown.

Comment: I was looking for something like system sockets to be honest, but I don't know much node.js and the doc isn't properly organized in my opinion so I've not found something relevant :(

Comment: If you want to go sockets, see http://socket.io/.  You could basically keep one socket open between your app and the node.js server and then just keep sending your data back and forth.  Still think you're better off just redoing it in python if you just want optimal speed.

Comment: Also, just took a closer look at that markdown parser.  I could be wrong, but I think that the parser blocks all the way which means your node process can only handle one request at a time.  Not good and might be the cause of your speed issues.  Can you try another markdown parser like https://github.com/chjj/marked?

Comment: If you really can't use any other parser, might try rewriting the of the parser at line:  for (var ctag = 0; ctag < tagcount; ctag++) { and using something like the node async library to make that part of the code callback friendly.  Although that might get gnarly since you have to control for matching end tags.

Comment: I'm investigating calling node from a system call instead of from http, not sure if it's a better idea but I might as well try it. I'll try to patch another parser in python if it's of no use. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

You are making no use of asynchronous design of node.js. In fact what You are doing IMHO is anti-pattern.

If You have to do calculations in node.js than server code is correct. But to leverage asynchronous architecture You should put many instances of node.js servers behind the load balancer. You can even run this instances on one machine to make use of multiple cores.

And to enable client to make profit out of that many instances You should make your post calls asynchronously too. To do it instead of requests use some async http client like http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html

It allows you to do computations in node.js instances in parallel.

Comment: well sadly I must process my entries one after the other so as anti pattern as it may be, I have to stick to it.